# JavaScript end of loop NaN for a numerical addition

Tags: javascript, arrays

when I run this program I end up with NaN at the end; I'd appreciate some form of explanation, as I'm stumped! I have an odd feeling it has to do something with scope...

https://jsfiddle.net/Smuggles/evj46a23/

```
var array = []

var range = function(start, end) {
  for (var count = start; count <= end; count++) {
    array.push(start);
    start += 1;
  }
  console.log(array);
}

var sum = function() {
  var result = 0
  var arrayLength = array.length
  for (var count = 0; count <= arrayLength; count++) {
    result += array[count]
    console.log(result);
  }
}

console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
```

Comment: You have to `return result;`.

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

1. You need to change the `for` loop in the `sum` function to be `< arrayLength` and not `<= arrayLength`. You are dealing with array lengths which start with a 0 index.
2. You need to return the result from the `sum` function

```js
var array = [];

var range = function(start, end) {
  for (var count = start; count <= end; count++) {
    array.push(start);
    start += 1;
  }
};

var sum = function() {
  var result = 0;
  var arrayLength = array.length;
  for (var count = 0; count < arrayLength; count++) {
    result += array[count];
  }
  return result;
};

console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
```

Given an array of `[4,5,6]`, the indexes would be as follows:

```
0: 4
1: 5
2: 6
```

Therefore, when you use the length property of the array (`3`), you are referencing an index that does not exist, which returns `undefined`. It tries to do the math on the undefined, which causes a `NaN`. This is why you have to use `< arrayLength`.

---

## The functional approach:

It would help to make those functions a bit more "pure". Instead of maintaining state outside of the functions (with `var array = []`), just return the values from the functions: See the following for example:

```js
function range(start, end) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
  return arr;
}

function sumArray(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  });
}

console.log(sumArray(range(1, 10)));
```

Each function takes arguments, and simply returns the result. This way, you approach this a little more "functional".

Answer (score 0):

Description in Comments of Code

```js
var array = [];

var range = function(start, end) {
  //simplified the loop to remove unnecessary variables
  for (; start <= end; start++) {
    array.push(start);
  }

  return array;
}

var sum = function() {
  var result = 0;
  // move length to scope of the loop
  // change to < rather than <= due to zero index nature of arrays
  for (var count = 0, length = array.length; count < length; count++) {
    result += array[count];
  }

  // return the result from the function
  return result;
}

// gets an array from 1-10
var arr = range(1, 10);
// print the array to the console
console.log(arr);
// print the sum to the console
console.log(sum(arr));
```